# Paypal Chained Payments PHP - Receiver needs to pay a percentage

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm having some trouble locating helpful tutorials or articles explaining if there's a way to extract a certain percentage from each receiver. Not to pay the PayPal fees but a fee for selling an item through my website. I took a look at chained payments but I don't want to take a percentage from the full transaction as it can be unfair if someone is selling an item for much cheaper than the other.

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you try masspay?

Comment: @amuroray Thanks for your reply. The reason being I won't be the one sending the money each time. I wouldn't like to have to create a list to whom to send the money to at each transaction. From my research I believe Chained Payments is the way to go except that i'm looking for a way to take commission from each receiver and not each transaction.